# How to make a custom attribute only apply to one element?

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating my own elements and attributes in HTML. However, if I apply my custom attribute to one element, it applies that attributes to the rest of the same elements on the page. I just want that attribute to be applied to the single element, not all of them.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

    <button rightal="true">Button</button>
    <button>Button</button>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="style.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
//Define all variables
var rightal = $("button").attr("rightal");

if(rightal == "true") {
  $("button").css("float", "right");
}
```

So my issue with this, is that when I add the `rightal` attribute to the first button, and set it to true, it aligns the button right just fine, but it also aligns every other button right too, I just want it to align the one button.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use the query string `button[rightall="true"]` to select only that button:

```
$('button[rightall="true"]').css("float", "right");
```

Note that non-standard attributes usually aren't a great idea - consider using `.data-` attributes instead, for example:

```
<button data-rightal="true">Button</button>
```

and

```
$('button[data-rightall="true"]').css("float", "right");
```

If no such matching element is found, no errors will be thrown (just like with your current code), there just won't be any DOM changes.